# How can I select text from Google Calendar's Agenda view in Chrome?

Tags: google-calendar, google-chrome

Sometimes I want to select text from the Agenda view of Google Calendar, but when I try to do so in Chrome, I'm unable to. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Update as of 2018-06-02: This is no longer an issue in the new version of Google Calendar that was released somewhere around late 2017/early 2018. You can now easily copy and paste text from the agenda view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple workarounds for this:

**The easy way**:

1. Open the calendar in Firefox, Opera, or Internet Explorer, as you
   can easily select text in any of those browsers

**The hard way** (but within Chrome):

1. In Chrome, open Developer Tools by hitting <kbd>F12</kbd> (or menu button -> More tools -> Developer tools
2. The Elements tab of the Developer Tools window should be selected by default, but if not, click it
3. Click anywhere in the code to put the focus on that window
4. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to search in the code
5. Search for "gridcontainer"
6. On the line where the text is found, right click and select "Edit as HTML"
7. Remove the text `id="gridcontainer"`
8. Click any other line to make Chrome show your changes
9. Select the text you want

Source: the 2014/01/24 post here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5429

Answer (score 2):

Install the StyleBot Chrome extension.

Select "Edit CSS" option for the default editing mode.

Go to Google Calendar, click on the StyleBot icon, click on "Open StyleBot" in the menu.

Enter the following CSS:

```
#gridcontainer {
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
```

Now you will always be able to select the text in the Google Calendar Agenda view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to copy it from other web browser and not from the Google chrome instance check the below details.

> try clearing the cache in browser.
>
> Check whether the chrome instance is latest one.

Note : If you are not able to copy the agenda from the global listing page. click more details hyper link available below each calender invitations to open the invitation in edit mode and copy the content